# Add vertical line to bottom css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a responsive table in twitter-bootstrap and I want to know if is possible to add centered line to the bottom of the "*numberCircle*" like in the image:

[image]

Thank you

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(177, 207, 219, 1);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="col-md-12 table-condensed cf">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">
        <div class="title">Title Content</div>
        <div class="content">
          Quisque porta pulvinar urna, at maximus sapien efficitur ac. Suspendisse tristique blandit tortor eget congue. Nulla sed aliquet enim. Ut quis massa auctor, feugiat dui ut, molestie mi. Ut congue metus ac neque vestibulum, et pharetra neque mattis. Suspendisse
          sed purus commodo, sagittis justo non, pretium diam.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center" style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">
        <div class="numberCircle">1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `:after` pseudo element

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(177, 207, 219, 1);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.numberCircle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<table class="col-md-12 table-condensed cf">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="title">Title Content</div>
        <div class="content">
          Quisque porta pulvinar urna, at maximus sapien efficitur ac. Suspendisse tristique blandit tortor eget congue. Nulla sed aliquet enim. Ut quis massa auctor, feugiat dui ut, molestie mi. Ut congue metus ac neque vestibulum, et pharetra neque mattis. Suspendisse
          sed purus commodo, sagittis justo non, pretium diam.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center" style="width: 50%; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="numberCircle">1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you like it to use for jQuery: add '<span class="numberCircleLine"></span>to numberCircle element " and alter css selector.

Comment: One small bug, can you align the number at the very top and make the bottom line 100% height? mean to put the td tag vertical-align: top; and the line to have full height